# Ошибки в совершенно пустом приложении Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Добрый день! Только начинаю изучать разработку приложений на Android Studio и уже существенные проблемы, о которых не говорится на многих обучающих ресурсах. Установил, создаю приложение и тут же возникают ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал создавать приложение под разные версии, использовал "Clean Project", но ничего не помогает. Странная буква "R". Программа либо не запускается вместе с эмулятором, либо приложение не появляется в эмуляторе. Что не так? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

ЮрийСПб, вы имели в виду это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Также покажите скрипты сборки `build.gradle` файлы (2 шт)

Comment: А `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` пробовали?

Comment: A. Shakhov попробовал, не помогло(

Comment: R это андроидный класс ресурсов. В Андроид Студио с ним давние периодические глюки. Обычно помогает Clean Project, но иногда нет. Причём один проект может глючить, а другой нормально работать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, так можете подсказать в чем причина того, что приложение не запускается на эмуляторе, если проблема не в R? Попробовал на телефоне, та же ситуация(